# Using classical inheritance, is it a good or bad idea to use 'class level' /member variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

We simulate classes in JavaScript using this kind of structure:

```
OurApplication.TableViewer = Class.extend ({
    init: function() {},
    viewLogic: function() {},
    logLogic: function() {}
}
```

Class.extend is a function that runs 'init' like a constructor and otherwise simulates classes in a somewhat Java-like way. I think this is similar to what Crockford calls 'classical inheritance' and this general approach (if not the exact syntax) seems to be somewhat commonly used/recommended, so I'm hoping that it's not controversial.

My question is, how data that is global to the 'class' should best be passed **between functions within the same 'class'**;

Method A:

```
OurApplication.TableViewer = Class.extend ({
    init: function() {
        this.foo = 'bar';
        viewLogic();
        logLogic();
    },
    viewLogic: function() {
        document.write(this.foo);
    },
    logLogic: function() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}
```

Method B:

```
OurApplication.TableViewer = Class.extend ({
    init: function() {
        viewLogic('bar');
        logLogic('bar');
    },
    viewLogic: function(foo) {
        document.write(foo);
    }
    logLogic: function(foo) {
        console.log(foo);
    }
}
```

I couldn't find a lot, but I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539652/using-a-class-variable-vs-sending-local-variable-to-functions-methods) which I think is the same topic but for Java. I would say it is barely favoring 'method A', but it's not at all clear.

Obviously there are some situations where it makes sense to pass data as a parameter (eg inside a loop where the value being passed changes each time; you could alter 'this.foo' to be the new value each time, but that seems awkward).

Any opinions/insights appreciated.

Comment: If you can pass parameters, your object has less state and is therefore easier to maintain. However, this is an opinion based question, which is not a good fit for SO. Go to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. If you think of a basic implementation of a "class" in JavaScript, global properties would be attached to the constructor, instance properties to `this` and public methods to the `prototype`:

```
var Car = (function CarClass(){

  // Private sutff to be shared with all instances
  var className = 'Car';

  // Constructor
  function Car(make, model) {
    // Instance properties
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
  }

  // Global public properties to be shared with all instances
  Car.colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'gray'];

  // Public methods
  Car.prototype = {

    // Method that uses private, global, instance and local variables
    getCarInManyColors: function() {
      return Car.colors.map(function(color) {
        return className +': '+ color +' '+ this.make +' '+ this.model;
      }.bind(this));
    }
  };

  return Car;
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that data that is member of a class (global to the class to use your own terminology) should never need to be passed to its functions, otherwise, what's the point of tracking it as a member field?

So the question becomes: should the data be a member of a class? And from an OOP point of view, if the data remains unchanged for reasonably long periods of time, it should. In other words, in your example, if the passed `foo` variable tends to stay the same when you call viewLogic and logLogic, then I would store it as a member.

If you like to use JavaScript in a more object oriented fashion, I'd urge you to checkout [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/)